# Integration over certain time in Modelica and write at certain points mean values in vector

Tags: integration, mean, modelica

I want to write a mean value at certain points in time in a vector.
My simulation is running for a year and I want to calculate a mean value for every day.

I have a variable in what is written what day of the year it is: `Real DoY;`
For every second my simulation computes a value: `Real value;`
So now i want something like this:

```
for i:365 loop
while i==DoY loop
 der(value_DoY_dummy) = value;
 value_DoY[i] = value_DoY/(34*3600);
 end for;
end while;
```

Of course, this is not working and I don't have any better idea. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Below is a code that sets the value of a variable at certain time intervals. Perhaps this will provide you with some idea of how to apply it to your case.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815089/how-do-i-gate-a-when-statement-in-modelica-to-limit-time-event-generation) may also be helpful to you.

```
model log Result
  Real value;
  Real savedValue;
  Real nextTime(start=1);

algorithm 

  value := time + 10;
  when time >= nextTime then
    nextTime := nextTime + 1.0;
    savedValue := value;
  end when;
end LogResult;
```

[image]